# zmq-cpp: recv() waits for data despite ZMQ_DONTWAIT being set

Tags: c++, zeromq, nonblocking

I'm trying to implement a non-blocking receive method with ZeroMQ using the `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` flag but `recv()` behaves like being called without the flag:

```
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto have_data = sock_->recv(&reply, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();

    std::cout << duration << " " << have_data;
```

`sock_` is a `zmq::socket_t` instantiated as `REQ` socket.

In this case `have_data` is always true and `duration` is whatever the `REP` server takes to reply (0 to several hundreds milliseconds).

Note that I'm talking about the cpp binding of ZeroMQ defined in `zmq.hpp` where `recv()`  is differently declared than in `zmq.h`:

```
inline bool recv (message_t *msg_, int flags_ = 0);
```

Here `recv()` returns `true` if data has been received and `false` if `errno` is `EAGAIN`

Are there any preconditions to `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` making `recv()` return immediately?

(I'm using `zmq` version 4.1.2)

Comment: REQ socket bind or connect? Add this part of code, please.

Comment: In my case it´s connect

Answer (score 2):

### Yes. <sup>( `ZeroMQ` preconditions should be taken into account. )</sup>

**A minor note:** ZeroMQ allows one to setup a [**`setsockopt()`** with **`ZMQ_RCVTIMEO == 0`**](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-setsockopt) or a performance-wise reasonable value.

The main issue however is hidden inside the **`REQ`**/**`REP`** behaviour pattern.

If an Application, on **`REQ`** "***jumps***" right into a state **`[*]`** and wait there for anything that might have already arrived into the **`[REQ]-<Rx>`**-buffer ( which is principally not possible in this use case ) or that might be will arrive, at some later time, but there is a trouble as the **`REP`** counterparty has nothing to reply to and must not and will not `.send()` anything without a prior `.recv()` a `REQ`'s request.

```
    ]-<Tx>- - - - - - - - - +                      + - - - - - - - -<Tx>-[
    ]-<Rx>- - - - - - - -+  |                      :  +- - - - - - -<Rx>-[
[REQ]____________________:__|                      :__|__________________[REP]
                         :  |                      :  |
APP.send() ]--->.send()--:->|                      :  |
           ]             |  :\                     :  |
           ]             |  : \____________________:__|>
           ]             |  :                      :  |M
           .             .  .                      .  .M
           ?             ?  ?                      ?  ?
           .             .  .                      .  .M
           ]             |  :                      :  |M_.recv()--->[ APP.recv()
           ]             |  :                      |  :             [ and
           .             .  .                      .  .             [ can 
           ?             ?  ?                      ?  ?             ?
           .             .  .                      .  .             [ 
           ]             |  :                      |  :             [    .send()
           ]             |  :                      |  :             [ after
           ]             |  :                      |  :             [    .recv()
           ]             |  :                      |  :             [ 
           ]             |  :                      |<-:--.send()<---[ APP.send()
           ]             |  :                     /:  |
           ]            <|__:____________________/ :  |
           ]            M|  :                      :  |
           .            M.  .                      .  .
           ?             ?  ?                      ?  ?
           .            M.  .                      .  .
[*]        ]            M|  :                      :  |
APP.recv() ]<---.recv()_M|  :                      :  |
                         :  |                      :  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the high level ZeroMQ api called czmq. It comes with ZeroMQ library.
It has function zstr_recv_nowait() details: [zstr man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/zstr)

Example:

```
//some code
void *listener = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_SUB); //zctx_t *ctx
//...
while (!zctx_interrupted)
{
     char* message = zstr_recv_nowait(listener);
     if (message && message[0]!='\0') {
      //do some work
     }
}
```

Comment: `zstr_recv_nowait()` actually calls `zmq_recv()` with `ZMQ_DONTWAIT`.